# Find a variable with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set the cell value as a variable an then use ctrl+f to find it in the spreadsheet, but I'm getting this message: Object variable or with block variable not set.

For instance, the cell A2 has the value of 1. I want that VBA look for 1 using the variable name.

Please see my code below:

```
Sub find ()

Range("A1").Select
Dim amount As String
amount = Range("A2")

Cells.find(What:="amount", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

End sub()
```

Comment: remove the quotes from `"amount"`

Comment: I can't believe I've missed this tiny detail.
Thanks for your help, it worked (:

Comment: Great - I'll put it as an answer. If you can check it as the correct one that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you've enclosed your variable in quotation marks - that in effect just treats it as the literal string "amount"

Simple answer is to remove quotation marks around any variable name
Use `amount` standalone

If you need to enclose a variable in a string you can concatenate and sandwich the variable between quoted strings. As in,
`"my amount is: " & amount`